# How to retrieve data from remote MariaDB server in Python

Tags: python, database-connection, mariadb

So, I have been pondering around on the internet in hope of finding some examples which shows how to correctly connect and retrieve some data from my remote MariaDB cluster. I just found one example: http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=2181112. But it did not include where to put **host argument** and the example shown are very limited. Usually, when I connect to my remote MySQL I use following like code:

```
def connect():
""" Connect to MySQL database """
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                                   database='test',
                                   user='root',
                                   password='qwe123')
    if conn.is_connected():
        print('Connected to MySQL database')

except Error as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    conn.close()
```

I need some workable examples like this. I would very grateful if someone provides some examples( *for connecting and querying* ).

Comment: I'm sure your dependencies are already fixated, but if in any way possible, have a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/). It's much more than just an ORM.

Comment: Be sure to include something like `charset='utf8'` or `'charset': 'utf8mb4'` if you will be using utf8.